Trying to replicate this Gantt chart
I want to replicate some Gantt charts shown in the book “Operating System Concepts” to demonstrate how CPU scheduling algorithms work, like this one:

I tried to replicate it using the pgfgantt package and this is what I got:
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{ganttchart}[%
inline, 
bar inline label anchor=west,
bar inline label node/.append style={anchor=west, text=black},
bar/.append style={fill=white!!black,}, 
bar height=.8,]{0}{30}
\ganttbar{$P_1$}{0}{24}
\ganttbar{$P_2$}{24}{27}
\ganttbar{$P_3$}{27}{30}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{figure}

which results in the following figure:

What I want to do (but am unable to despite reading the package documentation) is the following:

remove the top white bar
center the text of the respective blocks
make sure that the content of the figure does not exceed the allowed area on the page, at the same time keeping the numeric indices I used to define the “length” of each segment
have numerical indices, just as in the original figure.

I therefore kindly ask for help in resolving these issues.
Thank you

If what you want is what you hav shown in the image, why dont you use a table?

@yannisl sure, but I really need each segment to be x long by just entering a value (out of 30, in this case). Plus, I don't think I can get any number below each segment like in the original pic, can I?

If it's just this bar, you don't need a Gantt-chart: use Tikz. Look for inside https://tikz.dev/ : \node, its options draw and fill, minimum height etc. No big deal.

Following the @MS-SPO suggestions try this code:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
\filldraw[gray!50,draw=black] (0,0) rectangle (24,2) node[pos=.5,text=black] () {\large $P_1$} 
    (24,0) rectangle (27,2) node[pos=.5,text=black] () {\large $P_2$}
    (27,0) rectangle (30,2) node[pos=.5,text=black] () {\large $P_3$};
    \foreach \x in {0,24,27,30}
        \node[below] at (\x,0) {\scriptsize \x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

